# Data from an API is fetched successfully but it ain't loading on the page. Status code: 304 not modified HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
 <article data-index="1" data-status="inactive">    
        <div class="content" id="articleImage2">

            <p id="hiddenObject"> Enter details <br>
                <select id="branch">
                    <option disabled selected>Branch</option>
                    <option value="etc">ETC</option>
                    <option value="mech">Mech</option>
                    <option value="civil">Civil</option>
                    <option value="pei">PEI</option>
                  </select>
                  <select id="semester">
                    <option disabled selected>Semester</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                  </select><p>&nbsp;</p>
                  <button class="form-button" type="button" onclick="typeValue()">
                    Let's go!!! <i class="fas fa-rocket"></i>
                  </button>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <div>
              <p>Question papers
                <ul>
                  <li>Loading... ..</li>
                </ul>
              </p>          
            </div>
        </div>
      </article>
```

Javascript

```
// forms
let typeValue = function () {
  var branch = document.getElementById("branch").value;
  var semester = document.getElementById("semester").value;
  document.getElementById("hiddenObject").style.display = "none";
  var type = `${branch}-${semester}`;
  return type;
}

function queryQuestionPaper(dataIn) {
  fetch(URL)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(({ result }) => {

    let list = document.querySelector("ul");
    let firstListItem = document.querySelector("ul li");

    if (result.length > 0) {
      // to remove the placeholder content
      list.removeChild(firstListItem);
      result.forEach((data) => {

        if(data.type == dataIn) {
          let link = document.createElement('a');
          let linkItem = document.createElement("li");
  
          link.textContent = data.name;
          link.href= data.pdfUrl;
  
          linkItem.appendChild(link)
          list.appendChild(linkItem)
        }
      })
    }
  }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

if (window.location.pathname !== "/html/about.html") {
  queryQuestionPaper(typeValue);
}
```

The data was supposed to be shown on the screen. This is the working code that shows the data from the api call.

```
// forms
function navigate() {
  var branch = document.getElementById("branch").value;
  var semester = document.getElementById("semester").value;

  const baseUrl = `./${branch}-${semester}.html`;
  window.location = baseUrl; 
}
```

The new URL is constructed by concatenating the current URL of the page with the newly constructed URL. The newly constructed URL will be added to the end of the current URL, separated by a forward slash (/) character. */

```
// queries
// this is the CONTROLLER (selects queries based on the type of webpage)
// please review if you buy domain names!!
let type = function typeMaker() {
  const currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
  const urlParts = currentUrl.split("/");
  const lastPart = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

  const types = {
  "etc": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  "mecha": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  "civil": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  "pei": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  };

  for (const [prefix, suffixes] of Object.entries(types)) {
    for (const suffix of suffixes) {
      const expected = `${prefix}-${suffix}.html`;
      if (lastPart === expected) {
       return `${prefix}-${suffix}`;
      }
    }
  }
}
let typeValue = type();
```

The pages object is a collection of key-value pairs, where each key represents a category (e.g. "etc", "mecha", "civil") and each value is an array of numbers (e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]). The outer loop uses Object.entries() and destructuring assignment to iterate over the entries in the pages object. On each iteration of the outer loop, prefix is assigned the key (e.g. "etc", "mecha", "civil") and suffixes is assigned the value (e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]). The inner loop uses the for...of statement to iterate over the elements in the suffixes array. On each iteration of the inner loop, suffix is assigned the urrent element (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc.). For each combination of prefix and suffix, the code generates a URL string using template literals and checks if the URL is included in the value of currentUrl. If the URL is found in currentUrl, the code calls the function whose name is stored in the dynamic property of the window object. The name of the function is generated by concatenating the prefix and suffix variables and prefixing the result with "query_". Finally, the break statement is used to exit the inner loop if a match is found, so that the rest of the suffixes array does not get processed.

```
function queryQuestionPaper() {
  fetch(URL)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(({ result }) => {

    let list = document.querySelector("ul");
    let firstListItem = document.querySelector("ul li");

    if (result.length > 0) {
      // remove the placeholder content
      list.removeChild(firstListItem);
      result.forEach((data) => { // I'm fuming at this point!

        if(data.type == typeValue) {
          let link = document.createElement('a');
          let linkItem = document.createElement("li");
  
          link.textContent = data.name;
          link.href= data.pdfUrl;
  
          linkItem.appendChild(link)
          list.appendChild(linkItem)
        }
      })
    }
  }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

if (window.location.pathname !== "/html/resources.html" && window.location.pathname !== "/html/about.html") {
  queryQuestionPaper();
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try adding console logs or breakpoints throughout your code and make sure that the different variables get the values you expect.